# How can I open default browser in mobile webview

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am front-end developer, using javascript and vuejs..
Cuz our team's project was designed to use webview in native app, I'd developed mobile webview page for the app.
My trouble is that I dont have any experience in developing app, i dont know how to open user's default browser with my mobile webview code.

For example,
In our Team's app, there is a small web page. On the Header, I put a button named "CLICK"
When I click "CLICK" BUTTON, then i want to open default browser and a link to "https://www.google.com"

Is there any tip for my problem.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Launching native default browser
In native application we can launch the system default browser by sending implicit Intent.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

For your reference:https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent